# Value is not echo correctly

Tags: php

Im trying to obtain the number from the table and store it in a php variable but keep getting errors not matter watch mysqli_fetch I use

```
$sql ="SELECT price FROM rooms WHERE roomid = '$roomid'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)
or die ('Problem with query' . mysqli_error($con));
$price = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
echo $price;
```

If i try Assoc it will just display Array, if object shows an error What else should I try?

Comment: use print_r($price) to see instead echo

Comment: Try echo $price['price'] instead of echo $price...done

Comment: @ManinderpreetSingh thanks for that. So was the price correclty stored into $price? which fetch statement should be used correctly?

Answer (score 4):

`echo` does not print `array` and `object` to see use `print_r()` or `var_dumb()`

if you return array use

```
echo $price['price'];
```

in object use

```
echo $price->price ;
```